# F# - Remove duplicate characters after first in string

Tags: string, f#

What I am trying to do is to remove duplicates of a specific given char in a string but letting the first char to remain. I.e:

```
let myStr = "hi. my .name."

//a function that gets a string and the element to be removed in the string
someFunc myStr "."
```

where `someFunc` returns the string showen as below:

```
"hi. my name"
```

It is easy to remove duplicates from a string, but is there a way to remove the duplicates but letting the first duplicated element remain in the string?

Comment: Not familiar with F# but, you can create a list of characters by iterating through the string. The use the Contains method to check if a character already exists. If it does, skip,  otherwise add to the list

Comment: Azola's idea looks good, but I'd recommend making that a set instead since `List.contains` is O(N). Use [`Set.ofSeq`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/set.ofseq%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) and you should then be able to do lookups in O(1) time.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
let keepFirst c s =
    Seq.mapFold (fun k c' -> (c', k||c<>c'), k&&c<>c') true s
    |> fst
    |> Seq.filter snd
    |> Seq.map fst
    |> Array.ofSeq
    |> System.String

let example = keepFirst '.' "hi. my .name."
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let someFunc (str : string) c =
    let parts = str.Split([| c |])
    if Array.length parts > 1 then
        seq {
            yield Array.head parts
            yield string c
            yield! Array.tail parts
        }
        |> String.concat ""
    else
        str
```

Note that the character is given as char instead of a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
let someFunc chr (str:string) =
    let rec loop (a: char list) b = function
        | [] -> a |> List.rev |> System.String.Concat
        | h::t when h = chr -> if b then loop a b t 
                               else loop (h::a) true t
        | h::t -> loop (h::a) b t
    loop [] false (str.ToCharArray() |> Array.toList)
```

Note that the character is given as char instead of a string.

Edit: Another way would be using regular expressions

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let someOtherFunc c s =
    let pat = Regex.Escape(c)
    Regex.Replace(s, sprintf "(?<=%s.*)%s" pat pat, "")
```

Note that, in this case the character is given as string.

Edit 2:

```
let oneMoreFunc (c:char) (s:string) =
    let pred = (<>) c
    [ s |> Seq.takeWhile pred
      seq [c]
      s |> Seq.skipWhile pred |> Seq.filter pred ]
    |> Seq.concat
    |> System.String.Concat
```

Answer (score 0):

When devising a function, think about gains from making its arguments generic. To pass state through the iteration, barring mutable variables, `Seq.scan` could be a weapon of choice. It folds into a tuple of new state and an option, then `Seq.choose` strips out the state and the unwanted elements.

In terms of functional building blocks, make it accept a predicate function `'a -> bool` and let it return a function `seq<'a> -> seq<'a>`.

```
let filterDuplicates predicate =
    Seq.scan (fun (flag, _) x ->
        let p = predicate x in flag || p,
        if flag && p then None else Some x ) (false, None)
    >> Seq.choose snd
```

This can then easily reused to do other things as well, like [0 together with odd numbers](http://oeis.org/A004273).

```
filterDuplicates (fun i -> i % 2 = 0) [0..10]
// val it : seq<int> = seq [0; 1; 3; 5; ...]
```

Supplied with a call to the equality operator and fed into the constructor of `System.String`, you'll get near the signature you want, `char -> seq<char> -> System.String`.

```
let filterDuplicatesOfChar what s = 
    System.String(Array.ofSeq <| filterDuplicates ((=) what) s)
filterDuplicatesOfChar '.' "hi. my .name."
// val it : string = "hi. my name"
```