# Equivalent to Array.scan |> Array.skip 1, but without creating intermediate array?

Tags: f#

The `Array.scan` function returns an array of length `n+1`, where `n` was the length of its input array, and whose first item is the initial state passed to `Array.scan`. E.g.,

```
[|1;2;3;4|] |> Array.scan (+) 0  // Returns [|0;1;3;6;10|]
```

However, I usually find that that isn't what I wanted: I wanted an array of length `n`, *without* the initial state being preserved in my output array. I could easily get this result by simply doing:

```
input |> Array.scan f initialState |> Array.skip 1
```

But this will create an intermediate array which is immediately thrown away. Is there a good way to get this result without creating an intermediate array? I could easily implement that myself:

```
let scanWithoutInitial f initState input =
    let result = Array.zeroCreate (Array.length input)
    let mutable state = initState
    for i = 0 to (Array.length input - 1) do
        state <- f state input.[i]
        result.[i] <- state
    result
```

However, this seems like a lot of work to reimplement something that I would think would be in the standard F# core library. Is there a function that I'm overlooking? Or am I the only one with this use case, and most people want the initial value as the first item of their `Array.scan` results?

Comment: Could you create an [`ArraySegment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a new array?

Comment: @Lee - Hmm, interesting idea. Maybe. It would involve rewriting a LOT of my other code so that functions can take `ArraySegment` parameters instead of arrays, but maybe. I'll give that one some thought.

Comment: As to if you are the only one: Whenever I need a (new) function I will happily write it myself. Maybe others do as well? In that case you probably won't be able to tell if you are the only one.
There is one downside though; what to do once the function shows up as a standard function; refactor? leave it be? :-)

Comment: Unfold may offer some generalization, but it still lacks the prediction of the array length:
Array.unfold (fun (i,a) -> if i < Array.length input then Some (input.[i] + a, (i+1, input.[i] + a)) else None) (0,0)

Comment: Any reason 'Array.reduce' doesn't work for your use case?

Comment: @s952163 `Array.reduce` wouldn't result in an array.

Comment: Ah, yes,  derp. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mapFold](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharpdocs/issues/184) does exactly that:

```
Array.mapFold (fun acc x -> (acc + x, acc + x)) 0 [|1;2;3;4|] |> fst
```

For more of a brainteaser, ref [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42493303/4838058).

Comment: That's precisely what I was looking for -- and the fact that it hasn't been documented yet means I don't have to feel overly embarrassed for having overlooked it. :-)

Comment: it _was_ documented :P https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/list-module-functions/#19threading-state-through-an-iteration

Answer (score 0):

```
[|1;2;3;4|] |> Seq.scan (+) 0 |> Seq.skip 1 |> Seq.toArray
```